# What is the difference between checked and unchecked?

Tags: c#, checked, unchecked

What is the difference between

```
checked(a + b)
```

and

```
unchecked(a + b)
```

?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Those are operators that check (or do not check) for overflow in the resulting numerical operation.  In the `checked` case, an `OverflowException` exception is raised if the result of the operation exceeds the minimum or maximum value allowed for the datatype.

More information is available from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khy08726.aspx).

Comment: What is a practical reason to use checked or unchecked?

Answer (score 10):

It controls [overflow checking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx) for integer operations.

Answer (score 8):

if a + b is larger than the maximum value of the datatype, checked will throw an exception.  Unchecked will roll the overflow of the value and add it to zero.

Comment: you're right, I totally blanked about ints being signed.  I don't know where my head was.

Comment: The same will happen if a + b is smaller than the minimum value of the datatype, e.g. `a = b = int.MinValue` :)

Answer (score 7):

The [Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691349(VS.71).aspx) has a good article on the differences.

> The checked and unchecked operators are used to control the overflow checking context for integral-type arithmetic operations and conversions.

```
class Test
{
   static readonly int x = 1000000;
   static readonly int y = 1000000;
   static int F() {
      return checked(x * y);      // Throws OverflowException
   }
   static int G() {
      return unchecked(x * y);   // Returns -727379968
   }
   static int H() {
      return x * y;               // Depends on default
   }
}
```

Comment: I would like to know the reason why funciton G() returns -727379968!

Comment: @D.J. - It's because it overflows.  So you basically get ((x * y) mod 2^31) - 2^31

Answer (score 2):

The other answers cover the difference between the two. One thing worth noting is that if a and b are floats there will be no difference. It only works for integer operations.

There is also a build option you can set so everything is checked. This will mean your app runs slightly slower but you won't need to put checked around your arithmetic operations.

Here is a nice writeup that describes some pitfalls: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/overflow_checking.aspx