# Why use unchecked when casting this long to an int?

Tags: c#

In the [.NET Reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/NativeMethods.cs,101ceac68a3ac8ba), I saw this block of code:

```
public static int HIWORD(int n)
{
    return (n >> 16) & 0xffff;
}

public static int HIWORD(IntPtr n)
{
    return HIWORD(unchecked((int)(long)n));
}
```

and I cannot figure out why the `unchecked` is there. `n` is not a constant no matter what you pass it, so this cast is never checked anyways. For example:

```
public static void Main() { ConvertToByte(9999); }
public static byte ConvertToByte(int n)
{
   return (byte)n; // <-- this does NOT throw an exception
   // return checked((byte)n); // <-- but this WOULD
   // return unchecked((byte)n); // <-- this is POINTLESS
}
```

So, was putting `unchecked` in that `HIWORD` function just.. sloppyness?

Comment: There are options to set whether behavior in the absence of qualifiers should be checked or unchecked; I think the default is unchecked.  The unchecked qualifier won't matter if the configuration is set to use unchecked behavior in the absence of qualifiers, but adding it will allow the code to be used even when configured for "checked" behavior.

Comment: @supercat Ah! That makes sense.

Comment: Good to know, I would add as an answer

Comment: See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3772043) in the marked duplicate.